# Spring JPA JUnit test autowired failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following files:

### ProjectRepository.java

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {

@Query("select p from Project p where p.projectName = ?1")
    Project findByProjectName(String projectName);
}
```

### db-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.hcs.persistence"/>

 <!-- Working version of Oracle Database -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hrsdev.xxx.net:1548:hrsdev"
    p:username="xxx" p:password="xxx" >
 </bean>
 <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

### ProjecRepositoryTest.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:**/db-config.xml,file:**/persistence.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ProjecRepositoryTest {


public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectRepository.class);

@Autowired
ProjectRepository repository;

  @Test
  public void testProject() {
    Project project = repository.findOne(46L);
    assertTrue(project != null);
  }

public void setRepository(ProjectRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
}
```

I am getting this Autowired error:

DEBUG [main] (InjectionMetadata.java:85) - Processing injected method of     bean 'com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjecRepositoryTest': AutowiredFieldElement for com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjectRepository com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjecRepositoryTest.repository
ERROR [main] (TestContextManager.java:322) - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@60c9e03] to prepare test instance [com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjecRepositoryTest@351037b]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjecRepositoryTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjectRepository com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjecRepositoryTest.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.hcs.persistence.repository.ProjectRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)

The project structure is like this:

```
hcs-persistence
    src
        main
            java
                com
                    xxx
                        hcs
                            persistence
                                repository
                                    ProjectRepository.java
            resource
                db-config.xml
                persistence.xml
        test
            java
                com
                    xxx
                        hcs
                            persistence
                                repository
                                    ProjectRepositoryTest.java
```

I must be doing something obviously wrong. Please help.

this is the steps I followed: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/

Comment: the problem is that you don't load the config file correctly, can you post your project structure

Comment: You leave the `@Query` annotation. It's redundant.

Comment: I just added the project structure

Comment: try change `file: **/...` to 'classpath:db-config.xml', and make sure, you have a property called `projectName` in entity `project`

Comment: I changed the location to classpath*:db-config.xml,classpath*:persistence.xml and still getting the same error. BTW, it can't find the file if classpath without "*"

Comment: `classpath:/db-config.xml`, the asterisk means you wanna import more files

Comment: Your resources folder is named 'resource' instead of 'resources'. Try changing it and you classpath*:db-config.xml,classpath*:persistence.xml